# replace if statements by conditional operators in php variable

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I need to change my PHP code from: 
($a contains parsed text with html tags to which I want to append more data, checking if video links exist, append the echo statement)

```
$cont = '<div>'.$a.'<br>.'
  if (!empty($a->find('object', 0)->data)){
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$a->find('object', 0)->data.'">
    Play Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  }
  if (!empty($a->find('object', 1)->data)){
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$a->find('object', 1)->data.'">
    Play Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  }
.'</div>';
```

I know this is wrong so I need help implementing comparison operators.  Something like:

```
$cont = '<div>.'$a.'<br>'.
  ($a->find('object', 0)->data > 0 ? '<a target="_blank" 
  href="'.$a->find('object', 0)->data.'">Play Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;')
  ($a->find('object', 1)->data > 0 ? '<a target="_blank" 
  href="'.$a->find('object', 1)->data.'">Play Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;')
  .'</div>';
```

But I get a syntax error "(" by the first $a->find.  Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: You do realize that you are fundamentally changing the effect of the code, right? The first example has `echo` statements inside of the if's and the modifications don't.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do...see if the object exists and if it does, display something after the ? ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the else part introduced by a semicolon:

```
$cont = '<div>'.$a.'<br>'.
  ($a->find('object', 0)->data > 0 ? '<a target="_blank" 
  href="'.$a->find('object', 0)->data.'">Play Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;':'').
  ($a->find('object', 1)->data > 0 ? '<a target="_blank" 
  href="'.$a->find('object', 1)->data.'">Play Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;':'') // :'' here
  .'</div>';
```

Comment: Is my syntax right though?  Saying that it will be >0 is the same as saying (!empty)?

Comment: It's not the same; at least for negative integers: `!empty(-1) !== -1 > 0` ;)